# SSL warning in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I try to run hive commands,I get the following warning alongwith the output.

> Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is
>   not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+
>   requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit
>   option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using
>   SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need
>   either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set
>   useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification.

I tried to edit hive-site.xml jdbc url as

```
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true?useSSL=false</value>
```

But still I'm getting this warning.
What is the proper syntax to disable ssl?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSL=false</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `?` before useSSL to `&`.

(`jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false`)

The ? indicates the start of the query string. Within the query string you have a set of key=value pairs, each separated by an &.

Comment: It gives an error, `unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.sessionhivemetastoreclient`

Comment: need `&amp;` not just `&`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error.
I changed java 11 to java 8 then hive is working properly

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. (Append `useSSL=false` at the end of values as follows:)

```
<property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true;useSSL=false</value>
            <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
    </property>
```